# getting error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')" on useState usage react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, use-state

So I'm trying to use useState in my nextjs app, but as soon as I add in the line of code to initialize useState it throws a popup error with the error message: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')`

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Transactions />
        </div>
    )
}



const Transactions = () => {

    const [state, setState] = useState('test')
...
}
```

React/Next versions I'm running:

```
"next": "12.1.5",
"react": "18.0.0",
"react-dom": "18.0.0"
```

Screenshot of error from chrome dev tools:
[image: Screenshot of error from chrome dev tools]

Any thoughts on what's causing this? Thanks

***EDIT***
Very dumb bug on my end, issue was resolved by importing react...

Comment: I can't repro with the simplified version of your code, so there's a good chance the problem is in the details. Could you post a full example?

Comment: Repo link: https://github.com/bracesproul/Budget-Tracker/blob/main/pages/dashboard.js

Comment: @BraceSproul I have this error and I AM importing `react`. I'm using the latest nextjs, react and typescript.

Answer (score 18):

If you are using **Next 13 App router** this could be happening if you are using an async function

Wrong:

```
"use client"

export default async function Page() {
    const [variable, setVariable] = useState();
}
```

Right:

```js
"use client"

export default function Page() { //Remove Async Keyword
        const [variable, setVariable] = useState();
}
```

Comment: What if I need the function to be async though?

Comment: You need to use 'useEffect' to get the data and manage the page loading state using 'useState' @JackDamon

Answer (score 16):

**Just define State inside the Home function**

Comment: lol, I made this mistake. Thanks duh!

Comment: Could you share the fixed code?

Comment: can you help with a brief explanation as the nested component can also be having state.

Answer (score 5):

So I forked and cloned your github repo and was not able to reproduce the error on my system. One thing I found was in your navBar component you import

```
import Link from 'next/Link'
```

which threw me an error until I could change it next/link to lowercase

```
import Link from 'next/link'
```

What I would recommend doing is to reinstall react, just with a simple npm command to see if that fixes your problem. If not let me know!

```
npm uninstall react
npm install react@latest
```

Answer (score 5):

May you use "hook" outside of the function component because hook does not work outside of the function

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen because of the way you export the function:

**wrong:**

```
export default YourComponent();
```

**correct:**

```
export default YourComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a folder called "hooks" add paste this code there.
I was the same probleam and that worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error message and this line of code basically fixed it.

import React, { useState } from 'react';

Noticed that I had the incorrect import which was causing the issue on my end.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, the error is because `useState` is not being used inside the function that's being exported.
Just use `useState` inside a function and the issue will be solved!

Answer (score 0):

use the function as

```
export default function Register () {
  const [credentials, setCredentials] = useState();
```

This work for you

Answer (score 0):

Had the error even after importing react,usestate and even defined the usestate inside a function, but the actual issue was I was calling the function in the export line removed the () error resolved, Hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined `const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");` outside the component. Than this error may come.

Just move your `const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");` inside your component.

*Not working:*

```
const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");

const AppLayout = () => {
  return (
      <div className="app">
        <Header />
        <Body />
      </div>
  );
};
```

*Working:*

```
const AppLayout = () => {
const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
  return (
      <div className="app">
        <Header />
        <Body />
      </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score -3):

When migrating to **next** make sure you don't use any other Link except from next-js.

Answer (score -3):

Just reinstall the newest version react

```
npm install react@latest
```