# How to get form input value in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and using nextjs framework. Right now I have a form and want to get the input type text value am getting following error on my screen

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'useState' of null
```

Here is my current code:

```
<form onSubmit="{check_login}">

  <div className="form-group">
    <label>Username or email *</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="email"
      className="form-control p_input"
      onChange="{handleEmail}"
      value="{state.email}"
    />
  </div>

  <div className="text-center">
    <button
      type="submit"
      className="btn btn-primary btn-block enter-btn"
    >Login</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And for get value I am using following code:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({ email: "", password: "" });

const handleEmail = (e: any) => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  setState({
    ...state,
    [e.target.name]: value,
  });
};

const check_login = (e: any) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const email = state.email;
  alert("email is " + email);
};
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898427/getting-error-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-usestate-o

Comment: This looks like you forgot to `import` the `useState`. Can you post more of your source code?

Comment: `Cannot read property 'useState' of null` indicates that the property `useState` does not exist on `null`. Which makes sense because `null` doesn't have any properties. It should exist on `React`.

Comment: At the top of your file make sure you have this line `import { useState } from 'react'`

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing it wrong. Don't make an object inside the `useState()`
instead, separate out the email and the password and make separate `useState()` for them.
like :-

```js
const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
```

I have made a working example which might help you get a little bit more clarity on the topic. You can check out the CodeSandbox [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-smoke-7sfllh)

Comment: That's not the problem. It is valid to save a object inside a state, but your approach would be better.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it

Comment: Lol did you even read the question? There is an error coming up.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, just add `import { useState } from "react";`

Answer (score 0):

first you need add `import { useState } from "react";`
then your `value="{state.email}"` is not correct, JSX use `value={state.email}`, and the same for other parts